# Rounding a corner that's already been affected by a border-radius

Tags: html, css

The first image below shows the result I'm trying to achieve. (You may ignore the overlapping tabs for now)

[image]

And now below this is what I've already made. The yellow highlited bit is what I'd like to round out, how would this be achieved?

[image]

Here is the CSS being acted upon the active tab.

```
.productTabs>li.active>a, .productTabs>li.active>a:hover, .productTabs>li.active>a:focus {
  color: #fff !important;
  border: none;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  cursor: default;
  background: linear-gradient(225deg,transparent 29px,#1c83c6 5px)!important;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zc23s9j1/

Comment: Please post a jsfiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zc23s9j1/

Comment: maybe with a background image that was the same color as the grey background? This is a hard one, i'm not sure it's possible, especially with pure css.

Comment: Thank you, @Kay. I wasn't sure what to look for with this question, but I think that may help.